# PHPSpreadsheet: Is it possible to create a Hyperlink to a Named Range?

Tags: phpspreadsheet, named-ranges

Here's my code:

```
$spreadsheet->addNamedRange( new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\NamedRange('my_named_range', $worksheet, 'A1');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getHyperlink()->setUrl('my_named_range');
```

In theory this should put a hyperlink in cell B1 that links to the named range called "my_named_range" which points to cell: A1

Any thoughts on how to reference the named range in the setUrl()?

Any help much appreciated!

I know I could simply create the hyperlink to "sheet://'Sheet1'!A1" directly, but the thought is to allow the renaming of worksheets while not having to update all of the hyperlinks in my various sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
$spreadsheet->addNamedRange( new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\NamedRange('my_named_range', $worksheet, 'A1');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getHyperlink()->setUrl('sheet://my_named_range');
```

Just add "sheet://" before the named range to link to it, and editing the names of the tabs does not break the hyperlinks...